# Python dataflow DoFN class function finish_bundle running multiple times and giving empty outputs

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I am running a dataflow pipeline in which I have to collate the data into one Python dataframe for use in next step. So I use the `DoFn` class and define `__init__` , `process` and `finish_bundle` functions as below. I am hoping to get one output having all the entries collated into one dataframe. I feed this output into next step in the pipeline as a singleton side input.

```
class collate_ga_data(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self):
        self._ga_data = pd.DataFrame()
        self.window = beam.window.GlobalWindow()
        logging.info("In INITIALIZATION :   {0}".format(self.window))

    def process(self, element,window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
        self.window = window
        logging.info("In PROCESS :   {0}".format(self.window))
        self._ga_data=self._ga_data.append(pd.DataFrame({k: [v] for k, v in element.items()}))

    def finish_bundle(self):
        logging.info(" The shape of ga_dataset imported  :  {0}".format(self._ga_data.shape))
        logging.info("In FINISH BUNDLE :   {0}".format(self.window))
        yield WindowedValue(self._ga_data,0,windows=[self.window])
```

This code works perfectly using `Directrunner` and gives the expected results, but using Dataflow runners it throws an error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 649, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 178, in execute
    op.finish()
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 611, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 612, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 613, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 824, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.finish
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 808, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 834, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 806, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 398, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 401, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 959, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.finish_bundle_outputs
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 143, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 593, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 594, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 776, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 782, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 849, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/future/utils/__init__.py", line 421, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 780, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 587, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 610, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker._invoke_process_per_window
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/sideinputs.py", line 65, in __getitem__
    _FilteringIterable(self._iterable, target_window), self._view_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/pvalue.py", line 443, in _from_runtime_iterable
    len(head), str(head[0]), str(head[1])))
ValueError: PCollection of size 2 with more than one element accessed as a singleton view. First two elements encountered are "Empty DataFrame
```

I did some digging and found out that the DoFn is giving 3 outputs- 1 is the required dataframe and other two are empty dataframes. The finish_bundle is giving out 3 results. I am not able to figure out the reason behind this.  I don't want to use any windowing for this, but according the documents the output from finish_bundle has to be a windowed value, so I have a global window in there.

The logging info from the above  code is as below:

```
2020-02-27T16:32:45.331291913Z  The shape of ga_dataset imported  :  (0, 0) I 
2020-02-27T16:32:45.331489801Z In FINISH BUNDLE :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:45.390583276Z  The shape of ga_dataset imported  :  (0, 0) I 
2020-02-27T16:32:45.390754222Z In FINISH BUNDLE :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.639126300Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.641757011Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.644909381Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.647359848Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.649686336Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.651899814Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.654145240Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.656555175Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.658823966Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.660887002Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.663397789Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.665476560Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.667604684Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.669671535Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.672025680Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.674037218Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.676348209Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.678587436Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.680708885Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.682787656Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.685523986Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.687734365Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.689816713Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.691826343Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.693920373Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.696102380Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.698341846Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.700649023Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.703155755Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.705482244Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.707590818Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.709594726Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.711608886Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.713906288Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.716273546Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.718636035Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.720866918Z In PROCESS :   GlobalWindow I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.723044872Z  The shape of ga_dataset imported  :  (37, 8) I 
2020-02-27T16:32:48.723157405Z In FINISH BUNDLE :   GlobalWindow I
```

Dataflow uses only a single worker for this pipeline..Does anybody know why is this happening?

Comment: Hello. Such question will be worth sending to dev@beam.apache.org. Devs there can better answer questions related to core system.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Beam execution model](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/model/), "The division of the collection into bundles is arbitrary and selected by the runner." So that is why finish_bundle can be called multiple times.

It looks like your problem could be better solved by a CombineFn with CombineGlobally instead, using the DataFrame as the accumulator. Check out the [Beam programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms) (4.2.4. Combine) for instructions on how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. I was not able to use the CombineFn in my script, But it made me look at  `beam.combiners.ToList()` . This allowed me to create a single list out of the whole pcollection and then pass it into another fucntion that create a dataframe out of the nested list. [https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.2.0/apache_beam.transforms.combiners.html]

Comment: Be wary that a global combine and ToList() require all your data fit into memory which for many users this won't work.